# Using Android smartphone to connect to WHS (2011) via VPN

Tags: vpn, android, windows-home-server

I set up the VPN service at my Windows Home Server 2011. It seems that only SSTP as protocoll is allowed (only for Windows 7 computer and above). How can I connect via VPN from an Android 4.1 device to my WHS?

Because SSTP is not supported I cannot use another app. Can I change the VPN protocoll on the server side? Or is there perhaps another VPN server software which I should install? Or any other solution?

I opened the port 1723 for PPTP and it worked on the iPhone but not on the Android.

Comment: I have the same issue. If someone could help that would be nice